# Java Timestamp weird behaviour in storing 12 PM in different cases in Oracle Timestamp

Tags: java, oracle, date, timestamp

I am using Java's java.sql.timestamp and java.util.date for storing time in different tables of Oracle. All Oracle columns are Timestamps.

Problem is coming while saving 12:02 PM time(time between 12:00 to 12:59 PM). In some tables it stores it correct and in some its wrong i.e 12:02 AM

Here are the cases :

1) In java :

```
java.sql.TimeStamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
```

Above new Date() returns - "Mon May 16 12:02:02 EST 2016"

Oracle column mapping is with Timestamp only. In this particular table, it stores Oracle timestamp as-> "16/MAY/16 12:02:02.000000000 AM".
which is wrong because it should be PM instead of AM as the transaction were
executed in Noon.

In above table all timestamps in Oracle have 000000000 ms in the trailing.

2) In Java :

```
java.sql.TimeStamp timestamp2 = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
```

Above new Date() returns - "Mon May 16 12:51:01 EST 2016"

Oracle column mapping is with Timestamp only. In this particular table, it stores Oracle timestamp as-> "16/MAY/16 16/MAY/16 12:51:01.170000000 PM". Which is correct as it should be PM only.
In above table all timestamps in Oracle have some value in ms in the trailing.

3) In Java

```
Date date = new Date();
```

stores date directly in Oracle timestamp column and works fine. It stores 
"16/MAY/16 12:02:03.446000000 PM" in Oracle Column.

I don't understand why there is such difference in usage of timestamps.

I am using Hibernate to insert the objects in the database.

Can anyone please help in here ?

Thanks
Nitin

Comment: How are you inserting it into the database? Are you passing it as a bind parameter? Or as a string using dynamic SQL?

Comment: Are the columns that show the wrong time actually date rather than timestamp? I know you said they are all timestamp, but that seems not to be quite right - losing the fractional seconds suggests they might not all be. Or are some plain timestamps, and other are with time zone or with local time zone? If so can you check the session's NLS settings - I suspect there's an implicit cast or conversion that is switching from 12-hour to 24-hour format. Your actual NLS values would help explain it properly though.

Comment: @MT0: I am using Hibernate for database insertions.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Yeah all columns are plain Timestamps in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt on the correctness of your code. There is no class java.util.Timestamp, but a java.sql.Timestamp. And a "12:02 PM" does not make sense to me (it's in fact a "00:02 AM" of the next day).

You should first clearly distinguish between the internal format of a timestamp value and its string representation (on both sides: java and oracle).

Maybe your problem is based on the fact that you do not consider the time zone (Timestamp does not) of your timestamp. The java Timestamp class does not deal with timezones, it only contains an abstract long which indicates the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970. Your println uses your current locale ("EST") for the string rendering. Using another locale you get different values for the hour.

Oracle itself offers a datatype "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE".

If you are using java 8 I highly recommend to use the new Date API which deals with all the weird stuff around timezones. Further I recommend to normalize all timestamp values to be expressed in GMT timezone (i.e. timezone 0), programmatically save and transport the timestamp in this normalized format, and only on human input rsp. when rendering the timestamp for a human reader you should consider the format and the timezone.

Comment: I just corrected my question. Its java.sql.Timestamp.
And I can't use Java 8. In project its java 6 only. In oracle columns, 12:02 AM is stored. Don't know how that value is coming.